# PHP calling function within a class

Tags: php, json, wordpress, oop, json-api

I'm writing my own PHP class and I have multiple functions within the class. Something like this:

```
class JSON_API_Hello_Controller {

public function test_cat(){
    global $json_api;

    $posts = $json_api->introspector->get_posts(array( 'cat' => 3));
    return $this->posts_object_result_bycat($posts);
}

public function test_cat1() {
    global $json_api;

    $posts = $json_api->introspector->get_posts(array( 'cat' => 2));
    return $this->posts_object_result_bycat($posts);
}

protected function posts_object_result_bycat($posts) {
    global $wp_query;

    return array(
        'count' => count($posts),
        'pages' => (int) $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'posts' => $posts
    );
}

public function mix_cat(){

    $first_cat = $this->test_cat();
    $second_cat = $this->test_cat1();
   print_r($second_cat);

}

}
```

I want to call the `test_cat()` and `test_cat1()` functions in another function like `mix_cat()` inside the same class.  Every time, it gives the result of `test_cat()` and  `test_cat1()` as `Null`. How can I call the `testcat()` & `test_cat1()` functions in  `mix_cat()`?

Answer (score 0):

Your code calling the function looks good (`$second_cat = $this->test_cat1(); print_r($second_cat);`).

If the function returns a value when called from outside the class, then there must be some external variable(s) that we can't see here.  We might want to see more of the code, if so.

As a side note, you could combine the test_cat() and test_cat1() functions by passing a parameter for 2, 3, etc.  It would look something like this:

```
public function test_cat1($number) {
    global $json_api;
    $posts = $json_api->introspector->get_posts(array('cat' => $number));
    return $this->posts_object_result_bycat($posts);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response , actually when i tried function by passing a parameter for 2, 3 etc. i call the both function [test_cat() & test_cat1()] in mix_cat() function. then it return the result of test_cat() function only, not give the result of second function [test_cat1()]. it give the null value for test_cat1() function.   i tried call the fuction like this $first_cat = $this->test_cat(2);
 $second_cat = $this->test_cat1(3);
 print_r($second_cat);

Comment: print_r($second_cat); value did not display the data of test_cat1() funtion data. everytime it return the data of test_cat() funtion. Please try to help me.

Comment: As I look over your code again, I think your code is correct and it's working.  I think the problem is in the data.  There's a way to test this.  If you switch the "2" and the "3"...does the test_cat() return null and test_cat1() succeed?  If so, then your code is good and it's the data that is the problem.